# How to make Openwrt running on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openwrt

I have tried two methods to upload openwrt x86_64 image to AWS AMI and run on EC2, but both failed.

The image I built runs ok on VirutalBox and vmware.

### The first method - vm_import/export.

I followed instruction on https://amazonaws-china.com/cn/ec2/vm-import/, vm_import tool failed and said "Not found initrd in Grub" at last.

Openwrt doesn't use initrd at boot stage. This is the default boot entry of grub.cfg

```
menuentry "OpenWrt" {
        linux /boot/vmlinuz root=PARTUUID=fbdad417-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd
}
```

### The second method - ec2-bundle-image/ec2-upgrade-image

I tried this way, and it can upload image files and metadata files to S3, and I could make a new AMI, and launch EC2 instance. But EC2 instance was not be booted correctly it stop at the `grubdom>`.

I followed the instruction of https://forum.archive.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=41588, it seems a little old, I didn't found the aki instance it mentioned and used a alternative one (aki-7077ab11    pv-grub-hd0_1.05-x86_64.gz).

Whatever the combined image(openwrt default built) or the custom image(release rootfs.tar.gz and copy kernel and grub config to it), both failed, here is EC2 instance system log:

```
Xen Minimal OS!

  start_info: 0x10d4000(VA)

    nr_pages: 0xe504a

  shared_inf: 0xeeb28000(MA)

     pt_base: 0x10d7000(VA)

nr_pt_frames: 0xd

    mfn_list: 0x9ab000(VA)

   mod_start: 0x0(VA)

     mod_len: 0

       flags: 0x300

    cmd_line: root=/dev/sda1 ro console=hvc0 4

  stack:      0x96a100-0x98a100

MM: Init

      _text: 0x0(VA)

     _etext: 0x7b824(VA)

   _erodata: 0x97000(VA)

     _edata: 0x9cce0(VA)

stack start: 0x96a100(VA)

       _end: 0x9aa700(VA)

  start_pfn: 10e7

    max_pfn: e504a

Mapping memory range 0x1400000 - 0xe504a000

setting 0x0-0x97000 readonly

skipped 0x1000

MM: Initialise page allocator for 1809000(1809000)-e504a000(e504a000)

MM: done

Demand map pfns at e504b000-20e504b000.

Heap resides at 20e504c000-40e504c000.

Initialising timer interface

Initialising console ... done.

gnttab_table mapped at 0xe504b000.

Initialising scheduler

Thread "Idle": pointer: 0x20e504c050, stack: 0x1f10000

Thread "xenstore": pointer: 0x20e504c800, stack: 0x1f20000

xenbus initialised on irq 3 mfn 0xfeffc

Thread "shutdown": pointer: 0x20e504cfb0, stack: 0x1f30000

Dummy main: start_info=0x98a200

Thread "main": pointer: 0x20e504d760, stack: 0x1f40000

"main" "root=/dev/sda1" "ro" "console=hvc0" "4" 

vbd 2049 is hd0

******************* BLKFRONT for device/vbd/2049 **********





backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/27482/2049

2097152 sectors of 512 bytes

**************************

vbd 2064 is hd1

******************* BLKFRONT for device/vbd/2064 **********





backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/27482/2064

8377344 sectors of 512 bytes

**************************

[H[J


    GNU GRUB  version 0.97  (3752232K lower / 0K upper memory)





       [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For


         the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command


         completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible


         completions of a device/filename. ]






grubdom>
```

Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy task which doesn't need any of the complicated setup.
I used Virtualbox, but any other virtualization can be used (e.g. VMware or Hyper-V)
By my experience, placing openwrt to AWS fails using any of import methods other than "importing snapshot"

1. download openwrt

   - https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/19.07.5/targets/x86/64/
2. install openwrt on virtualbox and create ova

   - https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/virtualbox-vm

2a) convert img to vdi
- example: VBoxManage convertfromraw --format VDI openwrt-*x86-64-combined*.img openwrt.vdi

2b) extend vdi to 1GB
- example: VBoxManage modifymedium openwrt.vdi --resize 1024

2c) boot openwrt

2d) change eth0 interface to dhcp
- example: vi /etc/config/network

2e) shutdown

2f) export VM to ova'

3. rename .ova to .zip
4. unzip .zip

   - by unzipping you get vmdk file of virtual disk
5. upload vmdk to AWS S3 bucket
6. add vmimport role to your account

   - https://www.msp360.com/resources/blog/how-to-configure-vmimport-role/
7. import vmdk as snapshot

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-import-snapshot.html
8. create new EC2 instance
9. replace EC2 instance volume with imported volume

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html
10. boot up